# How to get any url to work for STATIC FILES with app.yaml in GAE?

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, create-react-app, app.yaml

I have a create-react-app Build directory, put it on Cloud Storage, added an app.yaml file in as well:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
  secure: always
- url: /
  static_dir: build
```

Hosted on app engine and voila - it works!

However, while *example-domain.com/* works, *example-domain.com/abc* doesn't. I get **Error: Not Found
The requested URL /abc was not found on this server.**

I tried replacing "/" with "/.*" in the handler url, but the result returns a blank page :(.

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: So it's this a [GAE app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website) or a [GCS-hosted](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) static site? Not the same thing... How are you deploying it?

Comment: I dump the build folder and app.yaml in GCS then use the console's SSH to copy the files and deploy them to app engine. like in:
https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-deploy-a-static-react-site-to-google-cloud-platform-55ff0bd0f509

Comment: OK, it's a GAE app but using GCS only as storage from where GAE deployments are done using the GCP shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. Turns out when I use static_dir, every url that starts that starts with that handler's **url** is included. Given that every static file is in the build/static dir, I just used **url: /static** for anything that needs to be handled from that folder.

Create-react-app creates several .json files which are in the build dir, so I just pointed to them individually since there only a few.

After all this is done I can use **url: /.*** to imply that any other url should just point to the index.html page.

This works: (The first handler is probably redundant)

```
  runtime: python27
   api_version: 1
   threadsafe: true

   handlers:
   - url: /
     static_files: build/index.html
     upload: build/index.html
     secure: always
   - url: /static
     static_dir: build/static
   - url: /manifest.json
     static_files: build/manifest.json
     upload: build/manifest.json
   - url: /asset-manifest.json
     static_files: build/asset-manifest.json
     upload: build/asset-manifest.json
   - url: /service-worker.json
     static_files: build/service-worker.json
     upload: build/service-worker.json
   - url: /pageIcon.png
     static_files: build/pageIcon.png
     upload: build/pageIcon.png
   - url: /.*
     static_files: build/index.html
     upload: build/index.html
     secure: always
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have duplicate handlers for `/`.  You will never get to the second handler.

You can serve static files of whatever kind you want using some regex in your handler, like so:

```
- url: /(.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg|html))$
  static_files: build/\1
  upload: build/.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg|html)$
  secure: always
```

Comment: how can I access .php files?